# C# View tables in datagridview based upon combobox item selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to load tables from database in datagridview based upon selected combobox item. I'm using entity framework. My code is as follows:

```
 private void btnCRUDLoadTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //prompt user when "Load Table" button is clicked without selecting any database or table or user 
        if (cboSelectDB.SelectedIndex <= -1 || cboSelectUser.SelectedIndex <= -1 || cboSelectTable.SelectedIndex <= -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Database, User and Table First");
        }
        else
        {
            //load data according to combobox selection in datagridview
            if (cboSelectUser.Text.ToString() == "User_name")
            {
                var context = new NameEntities();
                BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
                //here, instead of putting tablename is there a way to put 
                //combox item name? I have tried combobox.Text.ToString(), 
                //but it doesn't work, shows error 
                bi.DataSource = context.TableName; 
                dgvLoadTable.DataSource = bi;
                dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you mentioning that you getting error please show that error.

Comment: The error is: Identifier Expected

Comment: 1. `bi.DataSource = combobox.Text.ToString();` line gave this error? 2. Are you sure Text is not empty or null? P.s. Text is already a string so you dont need to convert it ToString.

Comment: I have used selectedText, just text, all shows the same error. I just simply want to use the selected combobox item name instead of putting the table name, so that I can view different tables using the same code

Comment: So add breakpoint and view what you have in `context.TableName` and `combobox.Text`. I bet content is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflation to set the table name dynamically. As below.

```
   var context = new NameEntities();
    BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
    //here, instead of putting tablename is there a way to put 
    //combox item name? I have tried combobox.Text.ToString(), 
    //but it doesn't work, shows error 
    var TableName = combobox.Text.ToString();
    bi.DataSource = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(obj, null);
    dgvLoadTable.DataSource = bi;
    dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

The TableName must be the property name created in NameEntities corresponding to the database table.

Comment: It says obj doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: @feather use context  instead of obj. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Now, it says nullReferenceExeption was unhandled

Comment: Check the value of TableName.And then check if that property exist in the context or not. TableName must be the name of the property that exist in context object. And that property represents that the desired table. In context the name of property may be different from the table name in the database.It has 's' appended to the table name in most cases. So you need to append the s if you are using the exact table name from the database.